# Cross domain file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using magento go to develop web store. It doesn't allow us to use any kind of server side scripting language like PHP. But I need to store order data after a successful checkout and provide the info to my shipping company.

Processing of data can be done in my web server but I couldn't pass data to my server.

For example, I need to pass data from abc.com to xyz.com/processdata.php

I can use javascript or jquery to do this.

I will appreciate for your help.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of, and what amount of data?

Comment: Magento's strongpoint is that you can use PHP to perform these tasks; I've built several Magento scripts. Why can't you use it? (Also, if you are running the script on a machine other than the one running the Magento store, you will have to connecto to Magento using the SOAP API. Also, I see no regular way of using javascript for this as Magento is built in object oriented php and javascript is inherently not object oriented (not enough, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can append a js returning php file in a script tag to your head with a parameter

```
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'http://remote.url/savemyinfo.php?parameter=yes';
   head.appendChild(script);
```

if the php file returns js, you can use it for feedback

savemyinfo.php :

```
echo("alert('saved')");
```